# Laravel ->with(") is there a way to use it with attributes?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I've been using ->("with) for relationships when querying models like so...

```
 return Model::
            where('set_id', $request->set)
            ->without('set')
            ->with('user:id,first_name,last_name,profile_photo')
        ->get();
```

Which works great for a relationship:

```
public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

But what about doing the same with an attribute?

```
public function getPermissionsAttribute(){
        $permissions = $this->permissions;
        $new = [];
        foreach($permissions as $p){
            $new[$p->permission] = true;
        }
        return json_encode($new);
    }
```

Is there a way to do this in laravel? As at the moment I'm getting the following error...

```
App\Models\User::permissions must return a relationship instance. (View: C:\Users\Nick\PhpstormProjects\laravel-vue\resources\views\index.blade.php)
```

I did have it in:

```
public $appends = [
        'full_name',
        'profile_photo_thumb',
        'permissions'
......... etc ............
    ];
```

But, the list was getting longer and I was sending out data to the front end that largely wasn't used, so was causing longer loading

Comment: so you want to append this 'attribute' (virtual) via the accessor to the serialized output for the Model instance?  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: Hey @lagbox. Thanks! I'm still a little non the wiser. I did originally have it in public $appends = [
        'full_name',
        'profile_photo_thumb',
    ];   -  but, The list was growing and I ended up sending data to the front end that mostly wasn't needed, so I decided to try and attempt to only send attributes that are relevant

Comment: well that is how you do it, via appends ... you can also do this at run time to decide what you want to send as the docs show ... you can also hide things

Comment: Yeah I tried this on a collection, and doesn't like it return User::withTrashed()->append('permissions')    -   error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::append()"

Comment: you didn't call that on a Collection, you called `append` on a Builder ... you would have to call it on an Eloquent Collection ... appending has nothing to do with the query

Comment: Thanks! An extra line of code did it $user = User::withTrashed()->orderBy('last_name', 'ASC')->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC')->get();
        return $user->append('permissions_alt');

Comment: Do you want to add an answer and I can set it as best?

Answer (score 0):

You can append accessor at Run Time to help you decide what data you want serialized in the response by calling `append` on your Eloquent Collection:

```
return $collection->append('attribute');
```

Or for multiple, you can pass an array:

```
return $collection->append(['attribute1', 'attribute2']);
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Serialization - Append Values to JSON - Appending at Run Time](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-at-run-time) `append`

Answer (score 0):

Try to get it by select function like this

```
return Model::where('set_id', $request->set)->with(['user' => function ($query) {
     $query->select('id','first_name','last_name','profile_photo');
}])
```